# frequency present in FFT but not in PSD

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density

I have a simple $0-40 \texttt{Hz}$ IIR bandpass filter.
With pure sine inputs I see $60 \,\texttt{Hz}$ is completely gone in the output FFT as expected by looking at the filter frequency response.

However I fed it with non sine signal+noise (i.e real world recorded signal), and I see the FFT shows a peak at $60 \,\texttt{Hz}$ . PSD though doesn't show any component at $60 \,\texttt{Hz}$ and it's flat zero.

I'm not sure how to interpret the FFT result. Why does the FFT have a peak where the PSD doesn't?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a definitive answer because I think your question needs a little more detail (see last paragraph), but since this is too long to write as a "comment", I'll leave this here for now and edit if need be.

---

Welch's method to compute the PSD uses frequency averaging. It basically computes FFTs on successive overlapping segments, and average them all together to give an estimate of the input signal's frequency content.

With that in mind, I'm going to guess the following:

- That your input signal has a strong $60\,\texttt{Hz}$ component
  *locally* (in time), but not throughout the whole signal. Because of that, the FFT, which looks at the signal in its entirety, picks up a
  small correlation with that component, but because the component only
  happens for a fraction of the whole signal, averaging all the FFTs
  results in that time-localized component to disappear in the PSD
  estimate.
- As @DanBoschen pointed out in the comment, it's worth mentioning that the PSD is shown in linear scale, which increases its visual range dramatically. Convert to a log scale for better comparison with the FFT result.

I suggest looking at a time-frequency representation of your input signal (such as a spectrogram) to confirm this, and I'll edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Stop band attenuation is in excess of 60dB. That's why I'm puzzled.

Comment: That's good. Now what about my other guesses? How strong is the component **before** filtering, and is it localized in time?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that data. I can imagine it's very strong but I can't imagine it's only localized in a small window of time.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have that data? Can't you just disable the filter ?

Comment: I wonder if the Welch PSD as shown is in linear magnitude while the FFT is given in dB? That isn't clear from the plot.

Comment: @DanBoschen I had noticed that and was going to mention, but the OP says "flat zero" so I figured it was something else. Eyeballing the dB values, the PSD component at 60Hz should have linear value around 1 (if constant 60Hz noise of course)... I'll add that to my answer though, as it's definitely worth mentioning

Comment: Yes, the decibel scale on the PSD will remove doubt.